# How to implement the concept of auto-increment in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to my field called as the `id`. But when I apply the following logic to write a query as follows:

```
CREATE Table address_book (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(40),
phoneNumber varchar2(11),
houseNumber varchar2(11),
roadName varchar2(40),
cityTown varchar2(40),
postcode varchar2(10));
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis creating table
```

Please guide me to effectively launch the query to implement the concept of `auto-increment` in Oracle.

Comment: There is no AUTO_INCREMENT keyword for Oracle and Oracle does not support identity columns untill 12C release. See please CREATE STATEMENT documentation by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm

Comment: So how would one auto increment a column?

Comment: For release 11.2 and below you can use BEFORE INSERT row-level trigger. For 12C use brand new IDENTITY syntax. Scan SO please - this question was discussed many-many times there.

Comment: Oracle should improve the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key word auto_increment is not a valid Oracle command.  You would want to use a SEQUENCE